# web3.contract.events.EventName.on('data', () => {}) expiring after ~15 minutes

Tags: contract-development, events, infura

I am using the following code:

```
const web3 = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(host);
const contract = web3.eth.Contract(...);

contract.events.EventName.on('data', console.log);
```

The `EventEmitter` for the `EventName` event works for the first 15 minutes, but after around 15 minutes of inactivity the events will stop being logged. I am using Infura as a web3 provider. I have setup code to automatically reconnect the `WebsocketProvider` should it disconnect but it is not disconnecting.

Anyone know a solution? Thanks.